# How to highlight UDL keyword only inside other delimiter?

Tags: notepad++, udl2

I want to recreate HTML as user-defined language. In HTML, attributes like `id`, `name` or `class` are only highlighted within HTML tags.

Like:

```
<span class="test">Hello</span>
```

How can I define in UDL that things like `value` or `name` are only highlighted inside a delimiter (in this case between `</>`)?

I tried to adjust which keyword groups were highlighted in the default style, but the "Nesting" options (where you could define what is highlighted inside this tag) are disabled for the default style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible within capabilities of the UDL 2, see them [documented](https://udl20.weebly.com/). You may reach for more complex UDL highlighters as the one in [SynWrite](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/). But with growing capabilities, they are also more slightly more difficult to master.

Comment: I don't see a reason why nesting options on the default style should not be a thing, but it seems that's how it is.

Comment: @ManuelHoffmann – UDL 2 appears to be without updates since 2012. Maybe this gives us a hint why it wasn't further improved or extended.